# Mysql schema on AWS RDS shows table which is not available in database meta data (information_schema)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, information-schema

I have a MySQL schema on AWS RDS where it has a table which is listed in the output of `show tables;` command but which throws an error when looking into the table structure using `desc <tableName>;` command. I have queried the metadata for any references for this table and cannot find any as well.

The weird thing is that we have set the mysql variable `lower_case_table_names=1` but this specific table was created with Uppercase names in table name. Unless it's possible to set this on session which I don't know of.

Output of show tables;

[image: Output of show tables; command]

Output/Error message of desc ;

[image]

Following commands to query the table name in metadata returns zero results.

```
select * from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.FILES where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.PARTITIONS where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS where REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.STATISTICS where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.TABLE_PRIVILEGES where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.VIEWS where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX where table_name like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET where table_name like '%tempPartInfo%';
select * from information_schema.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE where TABLE_NAME like '%tempPartInfo%';
```

At the moment any attempts to dump the entire schema fails at this table. And any attempts to drop the table fails as well with the same error message SQL `Error (1051): Unknown table 'v*******r.temppartinfo'`.

Not sure at which point this table was corrupted as I have the table structure in an older backup.

Any help to remove this table is appreciated.

Comment: Check if you're `temppartinfo` is view, not the actual table. There are high chances its `view` and not `table`.

Comment: @RedBoy Unfortunately that's not the case. information_schema.views has no record about such a view as well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not expert on this subject, just a thought if it could work for you, is to export all tables `except temppartinfo` and import the `exported data`. This will make your new instance `cleaner`, then refocus on remaining `tempartinfo`.

Comment: @RedBoy That's exactly what I thought as well. To export everything except for the corrupt table to a new schema. But since this is a production env and the schema is big, thought of asking around if there might be another solution to get rid of the corrupted table. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Any update on how to resolve this issue? :fingerscrossed:

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to fix this is to export the entire schema except for the corrupted table into a new schema.